# Using Python to create a sphere and map a texture onto it

Tags: python, texturing

Is it possible to map a texture onto a sphere using python script? I am sure it is, but so far I was not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Related, [How to get perfect UV sphere Mercator projection?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection).

Answer (score 1):

You should follow some beginner tutorials first, like [Blender manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python), to have an idea how to find yourself around Blender's API.

To get some feedback on comman tasks just pull down `Info Panel` or change the layout to `Scripting` like:
[image]

Now you will have feedback for all actions you perform like you usually would:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this post on Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-178488.html) could help you. It is covering version 2.5, but at least it can give you a direction to go in and help you know what steps are needed.

Here are some quotes from the thread:

[OP's question](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?178488-How-to-add-a-texture-to-an-object-with-Python-in-Blender-2-5&p=1562141&viewfull=1#post1562141):

> Just a very simple problem I think, but how can I make a little piece of
> Python 2.5 script for this :
>
> - Tell me which is the active object ?
> - Create a new material
> - Create a new texture : type Image or Movie
> - Load an image in the texture

[Successful answer](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?178488-How-to-add-a-texture-to-an-object-with-Python-in-Blender-2-5&p=1563396&viewfull=1#post1563396):

> ```
> import bpy
>
> def loadImage(imgName):
>     img = bpy.data.add_image(imgName)
>     tex = bpy.data.textures.new('TexName')
>     tex.type = 'IMAGE' 
>     print("Recast", tex, tex.type)
>     tex = tex.recast_type()
>     print("Done", tex, tex.type)
>     tex.image = img
>     mat = bpy.data.materials.new('MatName')
>     mat.add_texture(texture = tex, texture_coordinates = 'ORCO', map_to = 'COLOR') 
>     ob = bpy.context.object
>     bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
>     me = ob.data
>     me.add_material(mat)
>     return
>
> loadImage('/home/thomas/picture.jpg')
> ```

Give or take the snippets that you need.