# Creating a planet using grid and warp; texture is distorted?

Tags: texturing, uv

I was following [this short tutorial](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?111436-better-way-to-unwrap-a-uvsphere-for-planets/) about creating a planet by warping a grid or plane. It works great, but I'm having one problem: the polar ends of the planet (top and bottom) are sort of coming together in a point. It's really distorted. Here's a picture.[image: Planet distortion]

Here's one of my nodes and UV map.[image: Node editor][image: UV map]

I'm not sure if it's the texture, because everyone else was using Earth textures and I made my own in Gimp. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: See [How to get perfect UV sphere Mercator projection?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection)

Comment: @iKlsR The thing about an edge loop is actually something I tried, but I didn't think it was what people usually did. Thanks!

Comment: I marked it as a dupe since it correlates with the linked post and is basically asking the same thing, if you were after something else, just flag it for reopening.

Comment: @iKlsR I wasn't sure what to ask or what to look for, so I don't really mind.