# Why does the texture appear like this after adding a planet map texture to a UV Sphere?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I get the proper earth texture wrapping around the solid? I am listing how I executed it. Please show me where I am going wrong.
Here is a link to how I did it: https://vid.me/WpjH

Created a UV Sphere

Adding Material

[image]
Adding Texture

[image]
After Render

How do I fix this. How do I get the earth texture like it should be?

Comment: It appears by your map you have a mercator projection: Related    http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere/13928#13928  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection   Personally I like the grid warp warp method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the UV Sphere, tick Generate UVs in the left toolbar so the sphere is correctly unwrapped for applying that Earth texture.

[image]

Comment: just wanted to ask if i add Under Teturetab/ Mapping/Projection-->Sphere, then why does the image gets jumbled up?

Comment: I think you need also change the Coordinates to Generated. I personally never use this tab, sorry. I always use UV unwrapping.