# how do i properly texture a UV sphere

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

i was trying to make an eye, and this happened.[image]

is there a way i can texture a sphere without it replicating the texture?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection. That sphere has every face on the UV map of the same size as UV map.

Comment: How did you UV wrap the sphere before adding the texture.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U

Comment: What i did was open the texture, unwrap the sphere, and I then applied it.