# How to fix distortion in LWJGL using .obj

Tags: uv

I am a blender novice and was looking for some help. I have a UV Sphere that I unwrapped and applied a texture to. In blender it looks very good but when I export it as a .obj file and render it in LWJGL it distorts. How can I prevent this distortion?

[image: In Blender. Has no distortion.]

[image: In LWJGL. Has distortion.]

As you can see in LWJGL it has pretty bad distortion. My setting when exporting are: Include Edges, Write Normals, Include UVs, Triangulate Faces, and Objects as OBJ Objects. Any help on how to fix would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: I have tried both of these and neither fixed my problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Why what happened specifically that didn't fix the problem? "neither fixed my problem" is pretty generic. Also what is LWJGL and what does it have to do with Blender? If it only displays wrongly in other applications then it not a problem with Blender and doesn't belong in this site.

Comment: Im sorry. I should have been more specific. Both of those tutorials did not fix the distortion originally present for me. LWJGL is a Java Graphics Library and is the java equivalent to OpenGL. I posted this here because I assumed it was a problem with how blender was exporting the UV to my .obj file that is causing the distortion. I have previously never had a problem loading a texture with LWJGL and this is why I think it has to do with some blender settings.

Comment: We are more in these approach here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere. Anyway, you should start from a grid and make the grid spherical