# is it possible to unwrap an Icosphere in blender?

Tags: uv, geometry

well first of all , I need a triangulated mesh for an externa aplication, so I decided to use an Icosphere an export it then , however I noticed something ugly with Icosphere ... I would like to know if I could unwrap an Icosphere, here in blender.
I am not satisfied with "cylindrical proyecction"  and even with "smart UV" for triangulated mesh in this case, consider that icosphere is a triangulated mesh. I do not need quads  , trust me , I need an Icosphere and a well unwrap process. 
what  tools should I use to get a nice stretching with UV sphere?
 see this picture, is my best efford...but I am not sure ..

[image]
can you see it is an option called "generated UV's" in the "add ico sphere panel"... also there is subdivisions levels , size ...  I checked "generate uvs" and that is the result.... but this is not a good uvmapping process... I mean I would like to get NxN size of UV and aligned stretching... is it possible with triangles mesh as it??

Comment: Hi, you may be interested in [Mercator Projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89745/15543) which comes out reasonably well on icosphere, albeit without the poles.

Comment: it is an addon? I suposse , perphaps I will install it...

Comment: bit of synchronicity, your q popped up just as i was unwrapping icospheres for gif in answer.  Might expand out an answer here too.. but first need some sleep...

Comment: ok , if it works for 2.78 vertion? take your time I think blender needs addon for uv mapping.

Answer (score 13):

You will need to mark some seams. `Ctrl + E`, `Mark Seam` (and inversely `Clear Seam`)

An easy seam is one continuous seam around the sphere, which gives a good UV map when unwrapped.

[image]
[image]

Another seam type...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the seans will be visible from far away,  I need at least 8 pixels bleeding when I use manual marked seams...

Comment: I edited the answer with another possible layout of seams.

Comment: You did an excelent job of explaining my answer

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is mark seams, those are cutting lines for UV unwrap.

In Edit mode select a few edges.

Then menu at bottom goto : mesh\edges\mark seam

Then in edit mode, unwrap using <kbd>U</kbd> and select `Smart UV project`.

Comment: I know, but manual seams make issues , the best way to check this is open Unity and check the model from very long distance and the seams in blender are visible, the way to solve the seams is to make exagerated pixel bleeding or create a fake edge padding an check the "margin island" in bake option too.... how ever this is not a topic about seams..it is about projection...the best way to unwrap icosphere.

Comment: If you no what the final texture should be then try baking it, so you wont have to translate to some nasa moon picture into something that fit a specific icosphere.