# UV unwrap ico Sphere

Tags: texturing, uv

How can I UV unwrap ico Sphere in order to project a 360 image on its inner surface?

I need to use this model in Unity, so I have to be able to export UV layout along with the model.

The way I tried will cause a lot of distortion:
[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89735/is-it-possible-to-unwrap-an-icosphere-in-blender

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to UV unwrap your sphere at all. Just plug the Generated output of a Texture Coordinate node into your texture's Vector input, and set the projection (probably "Flat") to Sphere (or try Tube).

**Edit**: Missed the fact that this is for Unity. I will leave this answer here for others who just want to do it in Blender.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to write that the model will be used in Unity, in this case, can I export the UV map along with the model using this method, or is there another solution?

Comment: Well, with this method there _is_ no UV map. This method can't be exported, but Unity probably has something similar. (I've never used it myself, so I can't help you there.)

Comment: Ok, I need a solution for Unity, sorry for misleading you, but thank you, this method is also very helpful!