# UV unwrapping a cube that is convert to shere

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a question, after converting a cube to a sphere via subsurface modifier and then apply the "to sphere tool", what would be the best way to unwrap it to apply like a moon or earth texture on to it?

Comment: The best way would be to have it unwrapped *before* proceeding with all those operations

Comment: if you are only using subsuf modifiers that means that the basic geometry of the cube has not changed, so you can unwrap the cube as  you would normally do it.

Comment: Are  your planet textures are an [equilateral or similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) projection.  An example of [Mercator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89745/15543)  If so the issue is mapping the poles, the top and bottom line of the projection to the centre point  of top and bottom face of cube.