# exporting half an unwrapped icosphere to create geodesic map projection

Tags: uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to create a map projection of the northern hemisphere of the night sky on a geodesic dome. I naturally thought, "I can just project it as a material on an icosphere in Blender and then unwrap it!" but apparently it isn't that simple. (I'm new to Blender.)

[image: This is the closest I've gotten to a "net" for the icosphere.]

This is the closest I've gotten to a "net" for the dome, but I don't know how to export it as an image I can cut out and turn into a physical dome that doesn't distort the constellations or cut any stars out.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Reword your question as it seems to be about exporting, not unwrapping. And why don't you unwrap a UV sphere?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth i'm going to build a geodesic dome out of the net

Comment: If you're happy with the projection, you might want to look at the shipped 'Paper Model'  add-on. It will unwrap in a way suitable for folding, and bake textures to the UV it constructs.

Comment: Do you know the projection your night sky image .. eg [Mercator.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89745/15543)  Related https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18219/map-projections-used-for-star-maps

Comment: @batFINGER equirectangular!

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you! that's exactly what I need.