# Mapping an Aitoff projection onto a sphere

Tags: uv

Is it possible to map the attached image of the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) onto the exterior of a sphere in Blender? The few tutorials I saw use either sphere projection or mark seam, but those do not seem to reproduce the shape of this projection in the UV/Image Editor. By the way this is called an [Aitoff projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitoff_projection).

Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: CMB]

Comment: Do you need a UV map or a material nodes setting to do it?

Comment: @lemon What would be the difference? Sorry, I have little experience with Blender.

Comment: Actually, I went around my problem by converting this projection to an equilateral projection using the NASA software G.Projector, and then I could follow other tutorials for the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to do, it's like a bypass so maybe you won't like it, but at least it works not too bad ah ah.

- Find an Aitoff projection with longitudes and latitudes, for example the earth (if you come from this planet).

[image]

- Create a UV sphere with half the amount of longitudes and latitudes: here it makes a 12 segment and 6 ring sphere.
- Mark a vertical seam.

[image]

- Unwrap.
- On the *UV/Image Editor* stick each vertex to the point it is supposed to stick to. As there are half the amount of longitudes and latitudes it won't be tedious.

[image]

- If you want more precisions you can pin this first unwrap, add edge loops around your sphere and re-unwrap (here in my picture, more latitudes). Doesn't need a lot of adjustments this time.

[image]

- Give your earth a Subsurf modifier. Check if it's about correct in *Rendered* mode, i.e. if it looks like the actual earth (whew, it does).

[image]

- Duplicate your sphere, give it a new material, this time load your CMB picture in the *Image Texture* node.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, this is a great workaround! Better than what I did until now in any case.

Comment: glad you like it because it's a kind of trick, hard to find a way to properly unwrap, it looks like the Aitoff is pretty particular, but maybe someone will find another way?

Comment: I think if it's a one time thing (as it is the case for me), you could maybe double the number of segments and rings and spend more time on adjusting the vertices to obtain a very smooth map, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I've edited, use the pin tool if you want to add edge loops, it will make it more precise  ;)

Comment: Here is by the way how it looks like after converting the projection to equilateral, as I mentioned in the comments of the question: https://ibb.co/GVpD8HY

Answer (score 6):

**[Hammer Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_projection)**

[image]
*Nodes on left, UV map on right*

A while back, sh*t like 6 years ago,  I wrote a number of map projections, including [Mercator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89745/15543) and among them the [Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_projection), close relation to [Aitoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitoff_projection) which I've cleaned up for blender 2.8

[image]
*UVMap result on default UV sphere*

To use, run the script in text editor, or install as addon. Adds a Hammer projection entry to the UV mesh edit mode menu.

[image]

```
from numpy import sin, cos, sinc, arccos
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from math import degrees, pi, sqrt
import bmesh
import bpy
bl_info = {
    "name": "Hammer Project",
    "author": "batFINGER",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Mesh > UV UnWrap > Hammer Project",
    "description": "UV Hammer Projection",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "UV",
}


class Spherical:

    def __init__(self, vert, north=(0, 0, 1), long0=(0, -1)):
        self.vert = vert
        self.north, self.long0 = Vector(north), Vector(long0)
        v = vert.co
        R = v.length
        lat = pi / 2 - self.north.angle(v)
        is_pole = v.xy.length < 0.0001

        long = 0 if is_pole else v.xy.angle_signed(long0)

        self.R = R
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%.3f, %.3f, %.3f" % (self.R,
                                     degrees(self.lat), degrees(self.long))


class HammerUV:
    def x2(self, lat, long):
        a = 2 * sqrt(2) * cos(lat) * sin(long / 2)
        b = sqrt(1 + cos(lat) * cos(long / 2))
        return a / b

    def y2(self, lat, long):
        a = sqrt(2) * sin(lat)
        b = sqrt(1 + cos(lat) * cos(long / 2))
        return a / b

    # Aitoff equations (no joy)
    def x(self, lat, long):
        a = arccos(cos(lat) * cos(long / 2))
        b = 2 * cos(lat) * sin(long / 2)
        return b / sinc(a)

    def y(self, lat, long):
        a = arccos(cos(lat) * cos(long / 2))
        b = sin(lat)
        return b / sinc(a)

    def uv(self, face, uv_layer):
        ''' Map a UV face '''
        # see if face is east / west
        c = face.calc_center_median()

        for l in face.loops:
            luv = l[uv_layer]
            # apply the location of the vertex as a UV
            p = self.pts[l.vert]

            lat, long = p.lat, p.long  # % longfix
            # quick hack for now.
            if l.vert.co.y > 0:
                if c.x < 0 and long > 0:
                    long = -long
                elif c.x > 0 and long < 0:
                    long = -long

            u, v = self.x2(lat, long), self.y2(lat, long)
            uv = self.translate + self.scale @ Vector((u, v))
            luv.uv = uv


    def calc_uv(self):
        bm = self.bm

        uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()

        bm.select_mode = {'FACE', 'VERT'}
        bm.select_flush_mode()
        bm.select_flush(True)
        # adjust UVs
        for f in bm.faces:
            self.uv(f, uv_layer)

    def __init__(self, me, bm):
        def pt(v):
            s = Spherical(v)
            return s

        # add a new uv map
        uv = me.uv_layers.new(name="Hammer")
        me.uv_layers.active = uv
        self.bm = bm
        # spherical coords for verts
        self.pts = {v: pt(v) for v in self.bm.verts}
        # radius average of calc'd s.R
        self.R = sum(s.R for s in self.pts.values()) / len(self.pts)

        # scale UV to [0, 1] make scale matrix
        scale_x = 0.5 / self.x2(0, pi)
        scale_y = 0.5 / self.y2(pi / 2, 0)
        self.scale = Matrix([[scale_x, 0], [0, scale_y]])
        # and transform vector
        self.translate = Vector((0.5, 0.5))


class UV_OT_HammerProject(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Create a Hammer Projection UV Map"""
    bl_idname = "uv.hammer_project"
    bl_label = "Hammer Project"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH')

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.edit_object
        me = obj.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        merc = HammerUV(me, bm)
        merc.calc_uv()
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def unwrapmenu(self, context):
    ''' menu item '''
    self.layout.operator("uv.hammer_project")


def register():
    # add to edit mesh > UV menu
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.prepend(unwrapmenu)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UV_OT_HammerProject)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.remove(unwrapmenu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UV_OT_HammerProject)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Since it is a UV mapping can also use it on other spherical meshes like the icosphere

[image]

I added the code for the Aitoff projection, but have not quite managed to get that one "steady", not sure about the `sinc(...)` method required for that one.

**Using Nodes**

In https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159492/15543 dabbling in nodes I came up with a node setup to generate latitude longitude using object texture coordinates.

Basically the equivalent node setup to the script above, generating the UV and feeding into texture node.

[image]

[image]

[Tissot index hammer projection image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Hammer_with_Tissot%27s_Indicatrices_of_Distortion.svg) from wiki by Justin Kunimune [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)

Comment: nice! but I can't make it work on my 2.79 version, when I press U to unwrap I can see Hammer Project in the pop-up menu but nothing happens...

Comment: Clearly marked as being for 2.8. There are changes in API regarding uv layer name.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work for me in 2.8   :/

Comment: Added gif of me using it in 2.81.  There's not much I can do about it not working for you based on the comment _"it doesn't work for me"_

Comment: no problem, I was just testing, Jxx is the most interested ;)  edit: this time it was displayed in the unwrap menu but no result in the UV/Image Editor, but this is an old version of 2.8, so maybe it's the problem

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! I will give it a try tonight and see if it works on my 2.8 version.