# how to get texture interpolation to blend across UV seams

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking, texture-painting

I'm baking a star map texture to a high poly icosphere using "cubic" interpolation and noticed these hard edges along the uv seams.

first image is cubic and second is closest

[image]

[image]

is there anyway to get the cubic interpolation to blend across the seams so there's not that hard line?

Edit: i noticed it's possible to manually blend the texture across the seam in texture paint so that the seam is minimally noticeable (not actually gone but hidden better for sure).  It would be preferable if i could get this blur done in the initial bake process so i don't have to manually fix all the seams. So I'm also looking for bake setting that will better blend across the seams.

Other details to note: I'm baking to  high poly icospheres because the default unwrap has the most even pixel distribution as its mapped to equilateral triangles. This is already 16k bake texture so increasing res is out of the question. I plan to paint nebula's into this and render it out as an environment texture so these seams will be noticeable if they are caught in a zoomed shot. I also plan to use this baking method to turn other equirectangular planet textures from nasa into icosphere unwrapped textures for painting, so getting a clean blend across the seams is critical for the planets poles to look clean.

here's the icoshere uv bake shape in case that matters

[image]

Comment: I have to ask if you kept the default 16 px Margin for your bake? If you did, I am not understanding how you would need to blend the seams manually.

Comment: I did keep the margin, but the margin is only there to give the seams a cushion space before they're missing the texture. The margin doesn't effect how well the texture blends across one side of a seam to the other side.