# How to get uv map for mesh faces?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

This may be an unusual case, but I have an equirectangular image that I am wrapping onto a cylinder mesh using an environmental node on a bsdf material tab so that the end caps line up properly. The image wraps perfectly which is great. But I want to export this which apparently means I need a UV mapping but I cannot figure out how to make the UV mapping since there is no unwrapping of the mesh that matches how the image is wrapping to the shape.

I thought that perhaps if I could get the faces from the rendered mesh then they would map to the default unwrapping of the image (two circles and a rectangle) but what I currently get is a rectangular image in the UV plane with the cylinder shapes randomly on top of it.

Has anyone got experience with this?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160974/15543  in particular the warping of a 2 x 1 rectangle grid into a sphere. (an equirectangular projection) this way the pole faces are collapsed quads not triangles, but on the other hand the sphere is non manifold with holes at the poles.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties editor, in the mesh tab, UVs panel, you can manage UVs of your mesh as well as creating several UVs.

Note that one UV map in the list has the camera incon turned on: it means that UV map is used by default by your `image texture` nodes and by your `Texture Coodinates` nodes.

If you want to manually select a particular UV map from your shader, you will need to use the `UV Map` node.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that but my problem is more about getting the uv map that relates to what I am seeing on my object. The moment I try unwrapping the mesh then the image no longer maps correctly and I cant find any combination of settings that gets me back to the original projection of the image on the mesh