# Creating a UV Map from a shrinkwrapped sphere

Tags: uv, shrinkwrap

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but I try as good as I can:

I want to create a UV Map for a room with 8 walls that has a sphere shrinkwrapped onto it, so I can project equirectengular video material on it.

Has anyone experience with this?

So far I build the room:
[image]

and I shrinkwrapped a sphere onto it:
[image]

but the borderlines are weirdly pressed together so it's not just a clean edge and the corners are also filled incorrectly, is it normal in my case?
Do I have to merge along the vertices and the edges at the borderlines manualy, so that I can make a seam there for the UV?

Is there a better solution to shrinkwrap a sphere onto such an object to get a clean spherical UV?
Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spherical projection**

[image]

The above is the equirectangular projection of the Tissot Index Plate Carrie projection image found [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Plate_Carr%C3%A9e_with_Tissot%27s_Indicatrices_of_Distortion.svg) Justin Kunimune / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)  onto a squashed 8 sided ngon filled cylinder.

[image]

The node set up explained in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159492/15543

**A Hammer Projection**

and again using a Hammer Projection node setup as [explained here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148354/15543) of
[Tissot index hammer projection image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Hammer_with_Tissot%27s_Indicatrices_of_Distortion.svg) from wiki by Justin Kunimune [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)

[image]

Comment: Bottom line is: instead of wrapping a mesh, use a texture and do the projection on the mesh itself.