# How can I blend two objects i.e fillup objects between two different objects?

Tags: modeling

I have to make something like the design shown below in Blender.

I have done this in CorelDraw using the blend tool. I want to do the same for 3D objects. How can I do that in Blender?

2 different objects:

[image]

Blend between two objects:

[image]

Comment: you can use Shape Keys: Create your square plane, give it 2 Shape Keys, for the second one round it with right click > LoopTools > Circle, then play with the Shape Key value

Comment: Helllo :) @batFINGER made a script for this a while ago [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/122230/78972)

Comment: ...and this one   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121583/how-can-i-create-a-wallmesh-from-2-profiles-and-a-path-that-connects-them/122315#122315    Possibly also related. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce _eg of use_ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192234/is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-map-all-my-vertices-from-a-cubic-space-to-a-cy

Answer (score 6):

You can use Shape Keys: Create your square plane:

[image]

Give it 2 Shape Keys:

[image]

For the second one round it with right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

[image]

Then play with the Shape Key value:

[image]

Create as many duplications as necessary if you need to show a whole series of shapes.

Answer (score 4):

It does make a lot of sense using shapekeys as moonsboots answered.

Just know that there exist other way which uses displacement.
you can do more stuff procedurally by manipulating vectors (like a tilted transition in the illustrated image).

[image]