# i am trying to make a globe but my simple deform modifier is not working

Tags: modifiers

i am trying to make a globe but my simple deform modifier is not working
[image: veiwport]

[image: modifyer tab]

[image: entire screen]

Comment: related (begining of the answer): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197178/blender-project-a-map-on-a-sphere/198856#198856

Comment: no sorry it does not work

Comment: the only deformation thet seems to work is on th z axis

Comment: In the answer, I indicated to place the plane in edit mode along X/Y view (Z up).

Comment: i follow exactly how it ordered and this was the outcome  https://ibb.co/qBDC8fw

Comment: That's ok I think, just add (keep) your subdivision before all that (more than 2).

Comment: thanks! its finally works

Answer (score 0):

The page linked by lemon works, but you need to rotate the plane of the image 90 degrees on the x first and then ctrl+a to apply rotation. Or apply the 180 wrap first to the z and then the 360 to the x.