# How can I achieve this type of spherical unwrapping?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

**How can I unwrap a sphere like this?**

[image: How do I make this]

I can get about 1/3rds the way there by going to front view > selecting all faces > UV > "Project from View" But it's not at all optimized like the image above shows.

Here is a blend of the sphere with the UV mapping that I am trying to recreate here:

[image]

Comment: Suggest looking at https://medium.com/@k_serguei/spherical-coordinates-with-warped-poles-1b7f761541a6  Which can be mapped to UV,  done the other way _ie_ warping the UV sphere's poles, or via a node setup as demonstrated here with Hammer Projection https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148318/mapping-an-aitoff-projection-onto-a-sphere/148354#148354  (btw this still has 2 poles, unlike the backside shown above)

Comment: @batFINGER .. curious about where the 3 foci on the back come from. is this a spherized tetrahedron, 1 face on the front? No.. there would be 4. An inflated 3-cornered cushion? Not aware of any standard projection that would yield that..

Comment: My intuition is OP after result like in link (or as demonstrated by lemon)  In backside  follow the colours not the grid.  Hopefully OP will clarify. Wonder could the warp be done with modifiers and vgs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to deform a sphere and report its UVs on another sphere.

Use an icosphere with some subdivision (say 6).

In edit mode, change its tri to quads: select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (this matters for the UV tranfer operation later).

Back in object mode, copy this sphere.

Enter edit mode, in front view, select the four faces at the center. Turn proportional editing on, scale and enlarge the proportional editing so that its around all the vertices.

You should have something like this:

[image]

Once done, in front view, edit mode, select all and unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> then *"project from view (bounds)"*.

Back to object mode, select the original, shift select the scaled sphere and make links <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and choose *"transfer UV map"*.

[image]

And, voilà:

[image]

Other side:

[image]

Scaled UVs:

[image]

Comment: Going to test this out when I get to my office. This looks perfect. How does the front view look?

Comment: Just look at the pictures (front and back are there I think)?

Comment: Thanks so much, it finally worked after some trial and error.