# Guidance on creating a Celestial Sphere

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have a project in mind that I want to create with Blender. I'm trying to create what's called a

> **[Celestial Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere).**
>    In astronomy and navigation, the celestial sphere is an abstract sphere that has an arbitrarily large radius and is concentric to Earth. All objects in the sky can be conceived as being projected upon the inner surface of the celestial sphere, which may be centered on Earth or the observer. If centered on the observer, half of the sphere would resemble a hemispherical screen over the observing location.
>
> [image] Earth rotating within a
>   relatively small-radius geocentric celestial sphere. Shown here are
>   stars (white), the ecliptic (red, the circumscription of the Sun's
>   apparent annual track), and the lines of right ascension and circles
>   of declination (cyan) of the equatorial coordinate system.

I would like to create everything with objects, i.e. I'd like to avoid using a texture wrap on the entire sphere.

What would be a good way of achieving this ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741

Answer (score 1):

- Wireframe modifier is your friend when you need to create the grid of
  the outer sphere
- Constellations are just some vertexes connected with edges (the hard part is to put them in the right position - if you have coordinates you can insert them in the object properties > Transform > location XYZ attributes)
- you'll need to work with shaders to config how the edges are going to be rendered

Comment: For part 2 recommend the ephem module. https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/tutorial#computations-for-particular-observers